# Basic Forms [Javascript/HTML]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've just made a form for the first time.

I've a problem accessing the values of that form and storing them into variables, later used by functions. Whenever you submit the form, it take you to another webpage. **A JavaScript file is attached to both form and the another webpage.**

**What I've Tried** - **[If i give id to the properties]**

```
var someVariable = document.getElementById("Some id").val();     
console.log(someVariable); // It shows a error in console, not the value.
```

Another try

```
var someVariable = document.forms["Form Name"]["Property name"].value(); 
console.log(someVariable);
```

Some error in console.

**The Form**

```
<div id="ques">
<ul>
<form name="myForm" action="Answer.html" method="get">
<li>What cuisine?(You can leave it empty)<br>
<input list="Cuisines"  class="normal" type="text" name="Cuisine" placeholder="Like Chinese" pattern="Chinese|North Indian|Italian|American">
<datalist id="Cuisines" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="Chinese"></option>
    <option value="North Indian"></option>
    <option value="Italian"></option>
    <option value="American"></option>
</datalist></li>
<li>On a scale of 1 to 10, how much hungry are you?<br><input class="normal" type="number"  name="hunger" min="1" max="10" required></li>
<li><input class="special" type="checkbox" name="Personality" value="Vegetarian"checked> Vegetarian
<input class="special" type="checkbox" name="Personality" value="Non-Vegetarian" > Non-Vegetarian
</li>
<li>On a scale of 1 to 10, how much healthy do you want the food to be?<br><input class="normal" type="number"  name="Calories" min="1" max="10" required></li>
<li>What will be the max cost of the food, per person?<br>(Quality of the food will be affected)<br><input class="normal"  type="number" name="quality" placeholder=" Like 400" step="50" required></li>
<li>How many people?<br><input class="normal"  type="number" name="Amount of people" required></li>
<li><a href="Answer.html"><input class="normal" type="submit"></a></li>
</form>
</ul>
</div>
```

## EDIT

I works, with .value, how can i get it to log on both of the Webpages.

Comment: Use `.value` instead of `.value()`

Comment: Thanks! but still not complete, it logs, but on the forms webpage. I've used one javascript file on both of the web pages. Should i make another file?

Comment: If it's a completely separate page being reloaded, the script would get reloaded and the variables reset. You would need to find a way to either not reload or pass your variables via query string. Try looking into jQuery to modify the HTML dynamically so your variables are preserved or query strings to pass in when redirecting to the next page.

Comment: @bransonl `.val()` is the jQuery version of `.value`, not `.value()`.

Comment: @jon-kanter I recommended the use of `.value` instead of `.value()` as he/she tried `.value()` as a second attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` is a jQuery method for the value of inputs.

Try `element.value`.

---

Also, `xxx()` is always a function, but there is definitely no `value()` function available within an element.